# How do I show balloon when above data point is zero?

Tags: amcharts

I have a stacked, serial chart with chartCursor set to `oneBalloonOnly: true`.  Normally when I mouse over the chart, the balloon will display on the graph that is closest above or below my cursor.  However, if one of the graphs has a value of 0 at a given point, there's nowhere on the chart I can place the cursor to see the balloon for the graph below it in the stack: the balloon always snaps to the zero-value graph.

[image: Image of an AmChart]

How do I get the balloon to display for the red line at this date?

Comment: It's a known limitation with `oneBalloonOnly` and stacked charts. You need to disable `oneBalloonOnly`. Alternatively, you can write a `balloonFunction` that checks whether to include the top/bottom lines where needed but then you'll have one large balloon with multiple entries.

Comment: Thanks @xorspark That was my take away from the docs, just was hoping to find a different workaround before I go that route.